# corrupt language file en_GB.po

Tags: php, wordpress, corrupt

I have set up a site using Xmarket theme on WordPress 4.1.5 and everything was fine, I've transferred the site to a live host and now the language files seem to of been corrupted.
From what I gather they are stored in the wp-content/themes/xmarket/languages/en_GB.po as I found the msgstr in question being displayed as 'logaaaut' for logout and 'SAIGNNNN' for Sign In.

```
****example of the file****

#: et-links.php:13 et-links.php:14
msgid "Sign In"
msgstr "SAIGNNNNN"
```

I have edited these msgstr to show the correct values of Sign In and the same for Logout but it doesn't seem to of had an effect to the site.

```
****edited version****

#: et-links.php:13 et-links.php:14
msgid "Sign In"
msgstr "Sign In"
```

I have also tried to delete the language files and re-upload the non corrupt versions from the other working site but to no avail.

Bit stuck on what to try next.

Comment: upload how? ftp without binary mode, maybe?

Comment: after creating the database via phpmyadmin and editing my wp-config files I transferred over the files via FTP on Filezilla, the mode was set to AUTO. If I change that over to Binary can I just transfer over the language folder in question or should I do a full site upload again?

Comment: did you make sure to enable binary mode? if you don't, then the ftp client is free to apply text translation during transfer, and potentially corrupt any multi-byte chars.

Comment: Edited my original question in reply.

Comment: I changed the transfer type in Filezilla from auto to Binary and downloaded the uncorrupted language folder from the working host, went to upload it to the new host and it's still showing the wrong values, and this is with binary mode active when uploading the languages folder too.

Comment: I'm editing the en_GB.po with Sublime Text 2 if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised how this error has occurred, when I transferred the site to the new host I actually ended up changing the language from English (United States) to English (UK). 
Once changed back on WordPress Dashboard>Settings>General>Site Language it has rectified the mistake in translation.